# Java Jung subgraph components

Tags: java, graph, components, jung

I have an unconnected graph with several components. How can I get a Graph instance of each subgraph component? For example consider the following Graph:[image]

What I want is to be able to return these subgraph components. An example subgraph component would be the graph with vertices: {c0, c1, c2, c3}

I would like to come something like this (These classes don't exist):

```
GraphComponents<String, Integer> comps = new GraphComponents<String, Integer>(graph);
for(int i = 0; i < comps.size(); i++)
{
   comps[i].computeSomethingInteresting();
}
```

1. How can I return an instance of a subgraph component?
2. Which Graph type should I use (I am currently using a Forest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `getTrees()` command which returns the collection of trees in your `Forest`
More [info](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Forest.html#getTrees%28%29).

Comment: Yeah, this is a better answer for the specific case of a `Forest`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

WeakComponentClusterer will do it: 
http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/cluster/WeakComponentClusterer.html

Comment: Check out my other related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966684/java-jung-vertex-cuts-in-graphs

Comment: The next immediate question would be how do I construct a Graph<V, E> object again from a Set<Set<V>> returned from the WeakComponentClusterer.transform method?

Comment: As the Javadoc to which I linked says, `algorithms.filters.FilterUtils` will do it.  That said, @Origin's answer is better in the case of a `Forest`.