# Java Jung Vertex Cuts in Graphs

Tags: java, graph, vertex, jung

I am trying to do vertex cuts on graphs in the JUNG graph package. This is best explained by the following pictures:[image: Before the Vertex Cut]

Now, I am going to cut vertex "c1" out of the graph:
[image: After the Vertex Cut]

As you can see vertex "c1" has been removed from the graph, but so have the vertices "c2" and "c3"

**I want the vertices "c2" and "c3" to stay in the graph when I cut vertex "c1".**

I am using the `removeVertex(V vertex)` function to remove vertex "c1" from the graph.

1. How can I implement my code to keep vertices "c2" and "c3" when I cut vertex "c1"?
2. I am using a Forest as my graph type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at `DelegateForest` and its [`removeVertex(vertex,boolean)`](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/DelegateForest.html#removeVertex%28V,%20boolean%29) command which lets you specify whether or not to remove the entire subtree rooted in your vertex